# Loading files from disk using Emscripten async file system

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly, emscripten

I am trying to implement Emscripten [async file system](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html#emscripten-h-asynchronous-file-system-api) based file loader.Examples I found fetch URLs,but I want just to load a file from the system file dialog selection.

On C++ side I am using Embind API which at the high level looks like this:

```
 EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(LoadTest) {
 emscripten::class_<Loader>("Loader")
    .constructor<>()
    .function("LoadAsset", &Loader::LoadAsset)
    ;

 }
```

`Loader::LoadAsset()` function looks like this:

```
void Loader::LoadAsset(std::string url, std::string objectName,AssetType type)
{
   emscripten_async_wget_data(
            url.c_str(),
            nullptr,
            onLoadedData,
            onErrorData);
}
```

On JavaScript side I do this:

HTML input file tag:

```
 <input type="file" value="Load file" id="imagesFD" onchange="onFileOpen(this)" />
```

JavaScript:

```
 function onFileOpen(inputData) {
   var file = inputData.files[0];
   var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
   Module.GetLoaderSingleton().LoadAsset(url,"MyObj",Module.AssetType.Image);
 }
```

The URL path of the file looks like this:

```
http://localhost:5500/2e89f86e-fc64-4071-8046-48c2c257b432
```

When opening a file dialog and making a selection I am getting from webassembly:

> Runtime error:unreachable

Plus dump of the function call stack.

I have seen examples where a Uint8Array buffer is created on the client side and passed into WebAssembly,but I want to send down a URL/Path of the file and let my `Loader` module handle the rest using emsc async API.